# Using model binding with multiple users with the same inputs in a table with an ASP.NET Razor Page?

Tags: c#, html, asp.net-core, post, razor

I'm trying to populate a table with member information such as name, email etc. I also have columns for entering a "warning" for members, and a textbox where more information about this warning is entered. You're then supposed to press a button that posts this information, where it is then bound to a model and stored in a database.

By going the normal way and looping over the list and generating inputs for this based on the model, I run into issues (which I assume is due to the fact that there are multiple members in this table who all have the same inputs. This is the relevant code that I used in the MemberView.cshtml page:

```
@foreach (var user in Model.memberList)
        {
            <form asp-for="WebWarning" method="post">
                    <td>Regular member</td>
                    <td>
                        <select asp-for="WebWarning.WarningType" asp-items="Model.WarningTypes")"></select>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="WebWarning.Message"/>
                    </td>
                    <td>
                        <input asp-for="WebWarning.Person" type="hidden" value="@user" />
                        <button type="submit" class="btn btn-warning">Add Warning</button>

                    </td>
                    </form>
        }
```

Would anyone know how to get this to work? I've been trying (and failing) for hours now.

Comment: Why you set `asp-items` into `input` tag and please provide the error message.

Comment: Thanks for letting me know, I fixed this error and changed additional stuff in the code too! It still won't bind to the model like this, though..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

From your description in the question, I think you wanna bind multiple values with the same name. In this case, We usually set the index manually. Because you don't provide your model design, So here I write a simple demo, Hope it can help you solve this issue.

**Model**

```
public class User
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public string Message { get; set; }
    }

public class TestModel
    {
        public List<User> users { get; set; }
    }
```

**Controller**

```
public IActionResult Privacy()
        {
            TestModel test = new TestModel();
            test.users = new List<User>()
            {
                new User()
                {
                    Id = 1
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Id = 2
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Id = 3
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Id = 4
                },
                new User()
                {
                    Id = 5
                }
            };
           

            return View(test);
        }
```

**View**

```
@model TestModel

<form method="post">
    @for(var i=0; i < Model.users.Count; i++)
    {
        @*i configure the index manually*@
        <input name="users[@i].Id" value="@i" type="hidden"/>
        <input name="users[@i].message"/>
        <br />
    }
    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Now I input the value into `input` tag and it will the value successfully.

[image]

[image]

Comment: Hi @envydos, Does this answer can solve your issue?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if this is what you need, but you are missing the closing curly brace after your If Statement.

Comment: Thanks for the response, but I'm afraid that that simply got lost when I grabbed an excerpt of the relevant code and isn't an issue in the actual code :)

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).